# Can bind() socket to remote address?

Tags: c, sockets, bsd

With the following snapshot of C code, I understand that, the address that `bind()` call binds to  `listfd`, is the logical address of the local machine where this server program is running. Subsequently, server listens on `listfd` socket of that same machine.

```
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
listfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
bzero(&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(8000);
retval = bind(listfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
listen(listfd)
```

I learnt at [coursera](https://class.coursera.org/posasoftware-001/lecture/85) ---
that, `bind()` call also allow you to bind socket to remote address and port.

[image]
I would like to understand this point.

I mean,
    `listfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);`
provides a file descriptor from the program process where this program is running(local machine).

My question:

If bind() call binds this local socket `listfd` to a remote address instead of `INADDR_ANY`, then which machine is actually listening? Because `listfd` is an entry from local process file descriptor table of that local machine where this program is running and this socket `listfd` is getting bind to remote machine IP address? How do i interpret that? How does this work under the hood?

Comment: I suspect Coursera is guilty of insufficient editing. "local or remote address" should be replaced with simply "an address". The closest thing to "local or remote" dichotomy that makes sense would be "remotely visible or locally visible" address (as in an address bound to a network interface vs. loopback address). If you can, submit a bug report to coursera.

Comment: @Arkadiy Ah remotely visible, got you

Answer (score 5):

You cannot `bind()` to a remote address, at least not in the `AF_INET` family. According to the [man page of bind](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r13/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.r13.bpxbd00%2Fbind.htm), you will get a `EADDRNOTAVAIL` error, saying that the address you wanted to bind to is not local.

Edit: `bind()` *may* work for remote addresses but it certainly does not in the `AF_INET` family. Please note that there is more than this. There are probably some families that do indeed support binding to remote addresses, probably some clustering protocols. Even if there are not, `bind()` may work on those *theoretically* in case some protocols emerge where this makes sense at all.

Edit2: As [thuovila](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2011440/thuovila) pointed out, there actually is a case where binding on remote addresses in `AF_INET` works. That is, setting the `IP_TRANSPARENT` socket option before binding. [The man page of ip(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) tells us:

```
   IP_TRANSPARENT (since Linux 2.6.24)
          Setting this boolean option enables transparent proxying on
          this socket.  This socket option allows the calling
          application to bind to a nonlocal IP address and operate both
          as a client and a server with the foreign address as the local
          endpoint.  NOTE: this requires that routing be set up in a way
          that packets going to the foreign address are routed through
          the TProxy box (i.e., the system hosting the application that
          employs the IP_TRANSPARENT socket option).  Enabling this
          socket option requires superuser privileges (the CAP_NET_ADMIN
          capability).

          TProxy redirection with the iptables TPROXY target also
          requires that this option be set on the redirected socket.
```

So, with a lot of extra work, you can build a [transparent proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy) by tieing a local and a remote socket together with that socket option set (if I understand correctly).

Comment: Because (correct me if I'm wrong) with the local address, you are actually choosing which interface to listen on. So a remote address makes no sense.

Comment: I'm not sure how exact that is. You can have one (physical or logical) network interface with multiple addresses. AFAIK if you choose one of these addresses to listen on, you won't listen on the other addresses of that very same interface. So that word "interface" from the man pages probably don't mean exactly "network interface".

Comment: @Jan So, the source from where i learn this point is wrong info?

Comment: I don't know, the link requires authentication. Please read my edit though, bind may theoretically work for that but I don't know any families that support it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree the Coursera material is probably wrong or at least misleading for introduction level learning about network programming.

However, I can not suppress a pedantic comment. It is possible (on Linux) to bind to a non-local IP address. Please see option IP_TRANSPARENT at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html. This probably has very little to do with the issue at hand, though. Also i appreciate the question is tagged bsd.

More on the point, `bind()` does not have anything to do with listening. It simply associates the fd with an address. It is the `listen()` call that enables "listening". It is possible to `bind()` a socket used for outgoing connections.